# How to share multiple link using intent I have one link for android playstore and the other one is for iOS

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("text/plain");
                    String sAux2 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+appPackageName+"\n\n";
                    String sAux3 = "https://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/taxi-app/id1459541805?mt=8";

                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux2);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux3);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
```

I need to share these two links.
I am trying like this.

Comment: Why these 2 links when your app is going to be used in Android only?

Comment: I think you want to do like when the user shares in iOS, it should suggest you to share iOS link.

Comment: @PareshMayani app is used in both OS android and iOS

Comment: It is working fine for share as a text, but when I share with someone with facebook then it is not working because there is two links and app see these two links as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into Firebase Dynamic links... It is specifically designed to handle this. It will basically generate one link which will both work on android and ios.

You can configure it to open play store on android if app is not installed and similarly open app store on ios. There are other use cases as well.

Thus using the dynamic link you need to share one link which will do your job

https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links?gclid=CjwKCAjw-vjqBRA6EiwAe8TCk6S-nHZua1wB84Mlgou-k0r6UzFlriR7M_ZLUWy4xYkMnEN-p7g4ihoCAJ8QAvD_BwE

Comment: Or you can go with branch.io like third party services

Comment: True branch is pretty nice as well